# How do you hide a SearchController or make it smaller?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a SearchController with a search bar that is currently hidden. I do not need the user to be able to type in it. As you can see, there is a blank space where the searchBar would be:

[image: SearchController]

Is there a way to also hide this? Or to make it smaller or reposition it?

This is how I set up the searchController:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    initSearchController()
}

let searchController = UISearchController()
let searchBar = UISearchBar()

func initSearchController() {
    
    searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    
    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
    searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
    
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.isHidden = true

    searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: You are the one who is saying `navigationItem.searchController = searchController`. If you don't want the navigation bar to have a search bar, don't say that.

Comment: @matt The problem is that I do need the search bar and the searchController. The searchController is set as always active, so Strings can be passed into it via buttons and this filters a tableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the searchController if needed.

```
    let searchController = UISearchController()
    
    var hideSearchBar: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            navigationItem.searchController = hideSearchBar ? nil : searchController
        }
    }
   
    
    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        initSearchController()
        hideSearchBar = false
        
    }
    
    func initSearchController() {
        
        searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        
        searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = false
        searchController.searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func toggleSearch(_ sender: Any) {
        hideSearchBar.toggle()
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. For some reason the searchController is still there. My idea is to have a searchController that is always active but hidden. I have different buttons that pass Strings into it and filter a tablewViewController. Since the user does not need to type anything and just press buttons, I would like to hide it.  I know I can keep it active by using searchController.isActive = true in viewDidAppear, but I don't know how to hide it or make it smaller.